# Unhandled Promise Rejection error in a React/Next.js application when using openAI API

Tags: node.js, next.js, openai-api

I am working on a React/Next.js project. I have encountered an error related to Unhandled Promise Rejection in my code, and I'm struggling to resolve it. Here are the details of my issue:

**Error Message:**
[Error] Unhandled Promise Rejection: Error: The OPENAI_API_KEY environment variable is missing or empty; either provide it, or instantiate the OpenAI client with an apiKey option, like new OpenAI({ apiKey: 'My API Key' }).

**Code**

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { PrismaClient } from '@prisma/client';
import '@/styles/AskQuestionPopup.css';
import { getToken } from "next-auth/jwt";
import { db } from "@/lib/db";
import { OpenAI } from 'openai';

const prisma = new PrismaClient();

const AskQuestionPopup = ({ onClose, userId }) => {
    const [questionText, setQuestionText] = useState('');

    const handleQuestionChange = (e) => {
        setQuestionText(e.target.value);
    };

    const [validationMessage, setValidationMessage] = useState('');

    const openAIValidate = async (questionText) => {
        const OPENAI_API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY;
        const openai = new OpenAI(OPENAI_API_KEY);

        try {
            const response = await openai.createCompletion({
                model: "gpt-3.5-turbo",
                prompt: "Determine if the following text is appropriate: " + questionText,
                max_tokens: 60
            });

            return response.data.choices[0].text.trim();
        } catch (error) {
            console.error('Error with OpenAI validation:', error);
            return 'Error in validation';
        }
    };

    const handleAskPeers = async () => {
        const questionData = {
            userId: userId, 
            question: questionText,
        };

        const validationResponse = await openAIValidate(questionText);

        if (validationResponse === 'Appropriate') {
            try {
                const response = await fetch('/api/question/addQuestion', {
                    method: 'POST',
                    headers: {
                        'Content-Type': 'application/json',
                    },
                    body: JSON.stringify(questionData),
                });

                if (!response.ok) {
                    throw new Error('Network response was not ok');
                }

                const responseData = await response.json();
                console.log('Question added:', responseData);
                onClose();
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error submitting the question:', error);
            }
        } else {
            setValidationMessage('Your question is not appropriate.');
        }
    };

    return (
        <div className="popup-overlay">
            <div className="popup">
                <h1 className="popuptitle" style={{ color: '#f4f4f4', marginTop:'50px' }}>Ask a Question</h1>
                <textarea
                    className="question-input"
                    placeholder="Enter your question"
                    value={questionText}
                    onChange={handleQuestionChange}
                />
                {validationMessage && <div style={{color: 'red'}}>{validationMessage}</div>}
                <div className="popup-buttons">
                    <button className="ask-peers-button" onClick={handleAskPeers} data-text="Ask Your Peers"></button>
                    <button className="ask-ai-button">Ask AI</button>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    );
}

export default AskQuestionPopup;

export async function getServerSideProps({ req }) {
    const token = await getToken({ req });
    const userId = token?.userId; 

    return {
        props: { userId },
    };
}
```

I am using the Prisma client, Next.js, and OpenAI in my application. The error seems to be related to the environment variable NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY, but I'm not sure how to fix it.

Specifically, I need help with the following:

1. How to correctly set up environment variables in a Next.js application.
2. How to handle Unhandled Promise Rejection errors in a React/Next.js context.
3. How to configure and use the OpenAI client with the correct API key.

Any guidance, code examples, or suggestions to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance for your assistance!

Answer (score 0):

**Setting Up Environment Variables:**

1. Create a .env.local file in your project's root directory.
2. Add NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY=your_api_key_here to this file.
3. In Next.js, environment variables prefixed with NEXT_PUBLIC_ are
   exposed to the browser.
4. Ensure this variable contains your OpenAI API key.

**Handling Unhandled Promise Rejection:**

5. Always use try...catch blocks when dealing with promises or async
6. In your openAIValidate and handleAskPeers functions, add catch
   blocks to handle potential errors.

**Configuring OpenAI Client:**

7. Ensure your API key is correctly set in the environment variable.
8. When creating the OpenAI instance, check if the key exists: if
   (!OPENAI_API_KEY) throw new Error("OpenAI API key is missing");.

**Code Examples:**

Handling Unhandled Promise Rejection in handleAskPeers Function:

```
const handleAskPeers = async () => {
    try {
        const validationResponse = await openAIValidate(questionText);
        // Rest of your code...
    } catch (error) {
        console.error('Error during question processing:', error);
        // Handle the error appropriately
    }
};
```

Configuring OpenAI Client in openAIValidate Function:

```
const openAIValidate = async (questionText) => {
    const OPENAI_API_KEY = process.env.NEXT_PUBLIC_OPENAI_API_KEY;
    if (!OPENAI_API_KEY) {
        throw new Error("OpenAI API key is missing");
    }
    const openai = new OpenAI(OPENAI_API_KEY);
    // Rest of your function...
};
```

Comment: I already tried this but it didn't work

Comment: what error do you get? what's the feedback?